# On mouse hover, display a text like a dropdown for <th> tag

Tags: jquery, hover, html-table, mouseover, mousehover

I want to display a list of sub applications on mouse hover App1, app2 and app3 th tags. list of sub apps should be displayed one below the other. Below is my sample code, please help me.

This is my JSFiddle [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kh4VY/450/)

```
<table id="fooBar" border="0">
        <tr>
        <th>App1</th>
  <th>App2</th>
  <th>App3</th><th>
  </tr>
        <tr class="">
        <td>Text</td>
        <td></td>
        <td> </td>
        <td> </td>

        </tr>
        <tr class="alt">
        <td>Text</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>

        </tr>
        <tr class="">
        <td>Text</td>
        <td></td>
        <td> </td>
        <td> </td>

        </tr>
        <tr class="alt">
        <td>Text</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>

        </tr>
        </table>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
table{
width:100%;
border-collapse:collapse;
table-layout:auto;
vertical-align:top;
margin-bottom:15px;
 border:1px solid #999999;
  }

 th {
font: bold 11px "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, Arial, Helvetica,
    sans-serif;
color: #F2EDEB;
border-right: 1px solid #C1DAD7;
border-bottom: 1px solid #C1DAD7;
border-top: 1px solid #C1DAD7;
letter-spacing: 2px;
text-transform: uppercase;
text-align: left;
padding: 6px 6px 6px 12px;
background: #522D25 url(images/bg_header.jpg) no-repeat;
 }

 tr {
background: #fff;
color: #261F1D;
  }

 tr:hover, tr.alt:hover {
color: #261F1D;
 background-color: #E5C37E;
 }

 .highlighted {
color: #261F1D;
background-color: #E5C37E;
  }

  tr.alt {
background: #F5FAFA;
color: #B4AA9D;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this jQuery

```
$( "tr th:nth-child(n)" ).hover(function() {
    var index = $(this).index() + 1;
    $( this ).css( "background","#ff0000" );
    $( this ).parent().parent().find("tr td:nth-child("+index+")").css("background","#ff0000");

 });
 $( "tr th:nth-child(n)" ).mouseleave(function() {
   $( this ).css( "background","" );
   $( this ).parent().parent().find("tr td:nth-child(n)").css("background","")
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<style>
table{
    width:100%;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    table-layout:auto;
    vertical-align:top;
    margin-bottom:15px;
    border:1px solid #999999;
}

th {
    font: bold 11px "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, Arial, Helvetica,
        sans-serif;
    color: #F2EDEB;
    border-right: 1px solid #C1DAD7;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #C1DAD7;
    border-top: 1px solid #C1DAD7;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 6px 6px 6px 12px;
    background: #522D25 url(images/bg_header.jpg) no-repeat;
}

tr {
    background: #fff;
    color: #261F1D;
}

tr:hover, tr.alt:hover {
    color: #261F1D;
    background-color: #E5C37E;
}

.highlighted {
    color: #261F1D;
    background-color: #E5C37E;
}

tr.alt {
    background: #F5FAFA;
    color: #B4AA9D;
}

td {
    border-right: 1px solid #C1DAD7;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #C1DAD7;
    padding: 6px 6px 6px 12px;
}
   </style>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('th').hover(
  function () {
      $(this).html("<select><option>" + $(this).text() + "</option></select>")
  }, function () {
      $(this).html($(this).text())
  }
);


    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
            <table id="fooBar" border="0">
            <tr>
            <th>App1</th>
      <th>App2</th>
      <th>App3</th><th>
      </tr>
            <tr class="">
            <td>Text</td>
            <td></td>
            <td> </td>
            <td> </td>

            </tr>
            <tr class="alt">
            <td>Text</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>

            </tr>
            <tr class="">
            <td>Text</td>
            <td></td>
            <td> </td>
            <td> </td>

            </tr>
            <tr class="alt">
            <td>Text</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>

            </tr>
            </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you. but I want to display a hardcoded set of values on mouse over. I am not sure if i have to define those hardcoded value in separate div tag.pls help